# Performing silent update without play services in android

Tags: android

- I am using a application which cannot use google play services
- I cannot root the device
- I need to update the app silently without user interaction in the
  background

**What I found**: I found this resource called [InApp Update](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_o_q6hatcIs) but it uses play services

What is the best way to perform silent update in background
Does android provide any such features ?

Comment: I don't think there is any other way. Afaik only thing you can  do is to download apk in background launch and intent , but its not going to be silent .

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called hot-fix you can do it using this library

https://github.com/Tencent/tinker